# how to access hashtable values in powershell if hashtable is generated in a function?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have created a simple GUI to enter some values that are stored in a .txt file as soon as the User clicks OK. 
For verification I'm displaying the data of the just created file with its input in a popup window.

As I want to use the data of the config file in several other .ps1 files that I'm using for a project, I started to move things into a globals.ps1 file. Everything works great, with the exception that I can no longer display the hashtable.

Here's what I have in my globals.ps1 :

```
# Wshell popup
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.SHell

# read config
function readcfg
{
    Get-Content -Path $cfg | foreach-object -begin { $conf = @{ } } -process {`
        $key = [regex]::split($_, ':');
        if (($key[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($key[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True))`
        { $conf.Add($key[0], $key[1]) }
    }
}
```

And this is the part in my settings GUI which is executed if the OK button is pressed:

```
$cfgData = "
[Account]
Screds:" + $Admaccount.text + "
Spw:" + $PW + "

[Domainconfig]
Sdomain:" + $domain.text + "
SSearchBase:" + $searchBase.text + "
SdeactivatedUsers_OU:" + $deactivatedUsersOU.text + ""
    Out-File -filepath $cfg -inputobject $cfgData -Force
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $wshell.Popup("Settings saved:`nAccount: " + $conf.Screds + "`nDomain: " + $conf.Sdomain + "`nSearchBase: " + $conf.SSearchBase + "`ndeactivatedUsersOU " + $conf.SdeactivatedUsers_OU + "", 0, "Yarr...!", 0x0)
```

If I move the get-Content out of the readcfg function, I can display the values again. But that's of course not the solution, as it will display the old data if the settings are changed and the popup comes up again.

What am I missing here?

Comment: $cfg is never defined it seems. Your problem is certainly [a scope issue](http://www.sapien.com/blog/2013/03/06/first-rule-of-powershell-scoping-rules/) try to use the global prefix when you define it : `$global:cfg="c:\...." ` , use the same prefix inside your function

Comment: yes thank you. that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Kayasax in the comments, it was simply a "out of scope" issue.

after declaring the function and hashtable as global, it all works perfectly again.

```
# read config
function global:readcfg
{
    Get-Content -Path $cfg | foreach-object -begin { $global:conf = @{ } } -process {`
        $key = [regex]::split($_, ':');
        if (($key[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($key[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True))`
        { $global:conf.Add($key[0], $key[1]) }
    }
}
```